# Can I run copper wire to a subpanel via the crawl space without conduit?

Tags: subpanel

Can I run 3/0 copper se cable wire with the ground to a sub panel straight from the 200 amp breaker box to the 100 amp box through a crawl space without any conduit?

Comment: WHY are you running 3/0cu to a 100A panel???

Answer (score 1):

From the 2011 NEC 310.15(B)(7) table.
A 100 amp residential panel only requires #4 copper or #2 aluminum.
3/0 copper would be a waste of money.

If you use SE cable you will need 3 insulated conductors along with the bare wire.

> 338.10(B)(2) Use of Uninsulated Conductor. Type SE service-entrance cable shall be permitted for use where the insulated conductors are used for circuit wiring and the uninsulated conductor is used only for equipment grounding purposes.

Since you a using it for a feeder to a sub-panel you have to have an insulated neutral and use the bare for the equipment ground.

Do not bond the neutral and ground in the sub-panel and keep the neutrals and grounds separated. You need a panel that is "suitable for use as service equipment" since it will have an insulated neutral bar. Discard the green bonding screw.

Happy Friday!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you are sure that it cannot not be "...subject to physical abuse..."

Also, you can't use it underground (even in conduit).

Comment: Thanks that's great. Now I chose to use copper sense 1 panel the 200 amp will have connections (100)amp breaker then a 2' run to the crawlspace and then another foot out into the basement and to the sub panel so copper is required. Aluminum is way cheaper . is copper a better choice?

Comment: @SteveHowerton, what makes you think copper is required?

Comment: I am only aware that SE cable is required to feed a box. I also know that aluminum can corrode and get hot.  I am not aware of any calculation to determine wire size. If aluminum is actually okay that would be great because I will be adding an additional sub-panel to handle a smaller 60 amp panel that will have to run through joist on a 15 ft run. I just was assuming copper would be safer. Thanks.

Comment: I would use 2/0 or maybe even 1/0 for the 100 amp panel.  No need to go all the way to 3/0.  I believe 4/0 copper is good to like 200 amps or something, and the gauges increase by 10% each step, so you could go all the way to 1 gauge if you wanted to, but I would go 2/0 or 1/0.

Comment: I used 4/0 aluminum for the weather head to the main breaker panel 200 amps. On the last service it was 3/0 aluminum.  I just thought that was standard.  I will research and price 2/0 copper. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I am planning to daisy chain the main breaker panel 200 amps to a 100 amp sub panel and from the 100 amp subpanel to a much smaller 100 amp subpanel that will pull no more than 50 amps .I think I have decided to use aluminium does this sound okay if I put it in PVC all the way through?

Comment: Each panel is in the basement and each one is less than 20 feet one of the panels the conduit will run through a crawl space and the last one will run through the basement.

Comment: @SteveHowerton -- You do not *need* type SE cable to feed a box -- it just has to be suitable for the location and rated for the appropriate ampacity.  (I am sure that many a small subpanel has its feeder wired with NM!)

Comment: @SteveHowerton Do not confuse #2 with 2/0